# Set autorole on specific guilds only

Tags: discord.js

I'd like to auto set roles for new users when they join server X, problem is that this bot is on server Y as well, and server Y doesn't have the role.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log('User ' + member.user.tag + ' has joined Steampunk.');
  var role = member.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === "name");
  member.addRole('247442955651121154');
})
```

I was hoping that I could do a simple check before applying the role, if user have joined server X, add the role, if else, do nothing. So far my attempts have failed.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

The original code is trying add a specific role you put in, and not the role you just looked up a line before that. There shouldn't be any issues with other servers the bot is in, because `member.guild` gives the guild of the member object, and since this member object is coming from a guildMemberAdd it means that `member.guild` will only return the guild that was just joined. The code in the edit has a lot of strange things going on, though.

The first issue I see is that in order to look through the channels in a guild, you have to use `guild.channels.cache.find()`, `guild.channels.find()` is old now and doesn't work in v12. Same goes for `client.guild`, `guild.roles`, etc. The part at the bottom of your edited code doesn't seem to make much sense at all. The code should get the roles of the newly joined guild (`member.guild.roles.cache`), look through them to find the role you want (you did this correctly with the `.find()`) and then apply the role to the member. Neither `server` nor `role` ever get used in your code, and `guild.id` is a property, not a method.

Let me know if you need help following these instructions, although it looks like you should be able to do it now. Always look at the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) first to check properties, methods, etc.

Comment: I agree, the first code should work. It doesn't. If I join server Y(not the Steampunk one) with the first code, I get this output, since server Y doesn't have that role. 
`User tester57#5306 has joined Steampunk.
(node:21644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
    at GuildMember.addRole (/volume1/bots/Steampunk/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:452:38)`

I don't really care about the second code, was just your random 3 AM playing around.

Comment: Well, the first code gets a role with name "name" and then doesn't use it. The `member.addRole()` adds role 247442955651121154, NOT the role you just got the line before that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining the guild in question by name, saved it as a const, and made a check for the specific guild.

If your bot is on several servers but you only want the greet/addRole on a specific one, all integrated into the message displayed on joining;

```
//Welcome message and autorole for specific server and channel.
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const = client.guilds.find(guild => guild.name === "Steampunk");
        if (!guild) return;
         const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === "greetings");
            if (!channel) return;
  let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("#ff9900")
  .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
  .setDescription(`${member} Welcome to the Ark Steampunk Sponsored Mod Discord!\nPlease report all <#244843742568120321> and if u need any help view or ask your question in <#334492216292540417>. Have any ideas we got a section for that too <#244843792132341761>. Enjoy!:stuck_out_tongue: Appreciate all the support! <http://paypal.me/ispezz>`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter("Steampunk Bot", client.user.avatarURL);
    channel.send(botembed);
      console.log('User ' + member.user.tag + ' has joined ' + member.guild.name + '.');
  var role = member.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === "name");
  member.addRole('247442955651121154');
  });
```